# Set a specific horizontal direction that the UIScrollView can scroll to

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In UIScrollView, I've set the property pagingEnabled to YES, then How can I set a specific position it can scroll to? 
For example, i just want user to scroll it to right and forbid them to scroll it to left.

Comment: So after they scroll right (and stop) they can't scroll back to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control how the scroll can work by a combination of the `contentSize` and `contentOffset`. If initially you set the size and offset then as the user scrolls the offset will change. You can use the delegate methods to know when the scrolling has stopped. At that time you can change the `contentSize` and `contentOffset` to 'reset' the view so that it is back at the start (offset == 0). As part of the reset you will need to update the frames of the subviews of the scroll view (and probably remove the subviews to the left of the user offset).

Comment: Wow, that is a little tricky! I'll try it and i think it will work. Thx~